# how to check that socket is active on TCP layer?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, port, tcpclient

```
typedef unsigned int uint16;
SOCKET s, new_socket;
uint16 port =18001;

    void CreateSocket()
    {
            WSADATA wsa;
            struct sockaddr_in server;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number


                printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
            if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
            {
                printf("Failed Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                return -1;
            }
            printf("Initialised\n");


            //CREATING a SOCKET

            if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
            {
                printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
                //return 0;
            }
            printf("Socket Created\n");

            server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
            server.sin_family = AF_INET;     
            server.sin_port = htons(port); 
//Binding between the socket and ip address

    if(bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    puts("Bind Done");


    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);


    //Accepting the incoming connection
         new_socket = accept(s, NULL, NULL);

       if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
       {
    printf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(new_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
} 
       else
    printf("Client connected.\n");
```

closesocket(s);

```
        }

int main()
{
CreateSocket();

return 0;
}
```

this is for TCP.
I am receiving a connection from the MASTER via the above ip address and port number, So I created a socket with port number and ip address for it. But how to check that the socket is active ?? how to check that the above socket code is valid (it's not showing any error). I am getting an error on the MASTER side saying that :
CONNECT EVENT CHECK FAILED (WSAGetLastError())
Could anyone help me in this ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between your socket and the address, you never [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the address in `server` to the socket `s`.

Which, of course, is why your client fails to connect since the socket will not be using the expected port. I assume that you elsewhere call [`accept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and so on, to actually make the socket accept incoming connections, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I understand the missing part. BUT If i am accepting a connection from the client (Master : I am using a tool called INCA to send the connection command to server). Then what will be the accept call ?? (Because i did not created the socket on the Client)

Comment: Click on `accept()` above and read the documentation. The server  software needs to tell the socket layer that incoming connections are to be accepted on its socket.

Comment: I edited and added accept, bind and listen code in the above program. Then also Client is not able to connect. Could you please help me ??

Comment: Is the client on the same subnet as the server? Is the client attempting to connect to `192.168.0.1:18001`? That is where you are binding the server. You are also not doing any error handling on `listen()`.

Comment: what you said is correct. How to do error handling on listen (can you give me a example ) ??